# How to search in database where is array

Tags: php, mysql, android-sql

I've got this `mysql`query:

```
$Nusers = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM dotp_user_task_type WHERE user_task_types_id = '$select1'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

It takes all users id's which has task with specific id. So, now i need to take their name and last name but i don't know how to use WHERE when $row is array with numbers.

```
$Nusers = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(contact_first_name, ' ', contact_last_name) FROM dotp_user_contacts WHERE user_id = '$row'");
```

Help please.............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Using `IN` to search array value in mysql

```
$datauserid=array();

    $Nusers = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM dotp_user_task_type WHERE user_task_types_id = '$select1'");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Nusers))
{
$datauserid[]=$row['user_id'];
}
    $userid=implode(",",$datauserid);

    $Nusers = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(contact_first_name, ' ', contact_last_name) FROM dotp_user_contacts WHERE user_id IN ($userid)");
```

Comment: Your suggestion is best but how can i make it write only one time id because it writes `(
    [0] => 38
    [user_id] => 38
)` and it looks like 38, 38 it will look two times? Its when i fetch array

Comment: It worked perfectly, i need one more thing. is it possible to give user_id  for that [user_id] => contatct_fist_name contact_last_name? Because now its just increasing numbers

Comment: Here go to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940099/make-array-keys-user-id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86689/discussion-between-deena-and-mclaren).

Comment: i have answered this question.check it and let me know

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you combine both the queries like

```
SELECT CONCAT(contact_first_name, ' ', contact_last_name) as fullname
FROM dotp_user_contacts
WHERE user_id  IN ( SELECT distinct user_id FROM dotp_user_task_type 
WHERE user_task_types_id = '$select1' );
```

(OR) Using a simple `JOIN` like

```
SELECT CONCAT(duc.contact_first_name, ' ', duc.contact_last_name) as fullname
FROM dotp_user_contacts duc 
JOIN  dotp_user_task_type dtt ON duc.user_id = dtt.user_id   
WHERE dtt.user_task_types_id = '$select1';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `IN` -

```
" ....WHERE user_id IN (" .implode(",", $row). ")"
```