# Make array keys user_id

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hello stackoverflow people i need a bit help with this script. I need to change array keys. Ive got this script:

```
$Pirmas = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM dotp_user_task_type WHERE user_task_types_id = '$select1'");
if ($Pirmas) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Pirmas)){
        $firid[]=$row['user_id'];
    }
    $Pirmas=implode(",",$firid);
    $Antras = mysql_query("SELECT user_contact FROM dotp_users WHERE user_id IN ($Pirmas)");                                    
    //$Nusers = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(contact_first_name, ' ', contact_last_name) as fullname FROM dotp_contacts WHERE user_id IN ($Nusers)");
    if ($Antras) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Antras)) {
            $secid[]=$row['user_contact'];
        }
        $Antras=implode(",",$secid);
        $Trecias = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(contact_first_name, ' ', contact_last_name) as fullname FROM dotp_contacts WHERE contact_id IN ($Antras)");
        if ($Trecias) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Trecias)) {
                $thrid[]=$row['fullname'];
            }
            $key = array($Pirmas);
            $thrid = array_combine($key, array_values($thrid));
            print_r($thrid);
```

This script is to take user name and last name from database. It print information like this

```
array 
(
[0] => John Malkovich,
[1] => Tina Morgan
)
```

So my problem is that i need that key of this information would be the user id. Ive tried taking user_id's which is in the variable $firid and combine it like this:

```
$thrid = array_combine($firid, array_values($thrid));
```

But it prints:

```
[7] => John Malkovich,
[14] => Tina Morgan
```

And it should be 14 John. And 7 Tina. Please help me.

Comment: @NarendraSisodia It doesnt work because when there are more people here it is the id's `Array ( [0] => 38 [1] => 36 [2] => 13 [3] => 14 ) `And here is when i reverse `Array ( [14] => Scott 13 [13] => Kim 14 [36] => Vagner 36 [38] => Tom 38 )` Near name there is number how it should be

Comment: I didn't said that its an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
     $useridval=array();
            $secid=array();
            $Antras = mysql_query("SELECT user_contact,user_id FROM dotp_users WHERE user_id IN ($Pirmas)");                                    

                if ($Antras) {
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Antras)) {
                        $secid[]=$row['user_contact'];
                        $useridval[]=$row['user_id'];
                    }
            }
            for($i=0;$i<count($secid);$i++)
            {
                    $Trecias = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT(contact_first_name, ' ', contact_last_name) as fullname,contact_id  FROM dotp_contacts WHERE contact_id = '$secid[$i]'");

                            if ($Trecias) {

    if(mysql_num_rows($Trecias)>0)
    {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($Trecias);
                                    $thrid[$useridval[$i]]=$row['fullname'];
    }
                                }
            }

                print_r($thrid);
```

Comment: It should be oppositely, [14] => John Malkovich, [7] => Tina Morgan. Thats my problem :/

Comment: Ye it works perfectly just that i ned not contact_id but user_id is it possible somehow to change it?

Comment: your query is like contact_id=user_id.So the contact_id same as user_id.its have no problem.it is correct.

Comment: That is my problem. Contact id isnt the same as user id, thats why i was doing $Antras query. Look at my post :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86690/discussion-between-deena-and-mclaren).

Comment: check it and let me know

Comment: WORKS LIKE A CHARM, just that it doesnt print full name just first letter

Comment: Now i get Warning:  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given in ..... on line 116

Comment: I still get Warning:  Illegal string offset 'fullname' in. And it prints only first letter of the name

Comment: try $thrid[$useridval[$i]]=$row[0]['fullname'];
 to $thrid[$useridval[$i]]=$row['fullname'];

Comment: OMG YOUR AWESOME. Can i get your skype. I work a lot with this type of stuff. Sometimes i could ask your help, or email? :)))

Comment: I am always in stackoverflow.you can contact me here.:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$firid = array_reverse($firid); //reverse the $firid array
$thrid = array_combine($firid, array_values($thrid));
echo "<pre>";print_r($third);
```

Thank you :)

Comment: It doesnt workd because when there are more people here it is the id's 
`Array
(
    [0] => 38
    [1] => 36
    [2] => 13
    [3] => 14
)` 
`Array
(
    [14] => Scott 13
    [13] => Kim 14
    [36] => Vagner 36
    [38] => Tom 38
)` Near name there is number how it should be